# Extract multiple substrings of numbers of a specific length from string in Google Sheets

Tags: regex, string, google-sheets, split, google-sheets-formula

I'd need to **split or extract only numbers made of 8 digits from a string** in Google Sheets.

I've tried with `SPLIT` or `REGEXREPLACE` but I can't find a way to get only the numbers of that length, I only get all the numbers in the string!

For example I'm using

```
=SPLIT(lower(N2),"qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm`-=[]\;' ,./!:@#$%^&*()")
```

but I get all the numbers while I only need 8 digits numbers.

This may be a test value:

```
00150412632BBHBBLD  12458 32354 1312548896            ACT inv 62345471
```

I only need to extract "62345471" and nothing else!

Could you please help me out?

Many thanks!

Comment: I slightly changed your title to a more descriptive one. You can always change it back if you disagree.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use the following formula for a single cell.
Drag it down for more cells.

```
=INDEX(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IF(LEN(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(A2&" ","\D+"," ")," "))=8,
                                        SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(A2&" ","\D+"," ")," "),"")),"where Col1 is not null ",0)))
```

[image: Extract any number of fixed (8) digit substrings/clusters from a string/cell]

---

Functions used:

- [`QUERY`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343)
- [`INDEX`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098242)
- [`TRANSPOSE`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094262)
- [`IF`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093364)
- [`LEN`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094081)
- [`SPLIT`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094136)
- [`REGEXREPLACE`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098245)

Answer (score 0):

Using this on a cell worked just fine for me:

```
(cell_with_data)=REGEXEXTRACT(A1,"[0-9]{8}$")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to do this for one cell (or you have your heart set on dragging the formula down into individual cells), use the following formula:

`=REGEXEXTRACT(" "&N2&" ","\s(\d{8})\s")`

However, I suspect you want to process the eight-digit number out of all cells running N2:N. If that is the case, clear whatever will be your results column (including any headers) and place the following in the top cell of that otherwise cleared results column:

`=ArrayFormula({"Your Header"; IF(N2:N="",,IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(" "&N2:N&" ","\s(\d{8})\s")))})`

Replace the header text `Your Header` with whatever you want your actual header text to be. The formula will show that header text and will return all results for all rows where N2:N is not null. Where no eight-digit number is found, null will be returned.

By prepending and appending a space to the N2:N raw strings before processing, spaces before and after string components can be used to determine where *only eight* digits exist together (as opposed to eight digits within a longer string of digits).

The only assumption here is that there are, in fact, spaces between string components. I *did not* assume that the eight-digit number will always be in a certain position (e.g., first, last) within the string.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, take a look at **[Example sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1s00xnEtuf6VUR5h6jvRN05HZPIzvsX8ddC7xdov9_t0/edit?usp=sharing)**

```
=FILTER(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(B2," ")),LEN(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(B2," ")))=8)
```

> Or this to **get them all**.

```
=JOIN(" ,",FILTER(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(B2," ")),LEN(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(B2," ")))=8))
```

[image]

**Explanation**

- [`SPLIT`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094136?hl=en) with the dilimiter set to `" "` space [`TRANSPOSE`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094262?hl=en) and [`FILTER`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197?hl=en) [`TRANSPOSE`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094262?hl=en)`(SPLIT(B2," ")` with the condition1 set to [`LEN`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094081?hl=en)`(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(B2," ")))` is  `= 8`
- [`JOIN`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094077?hl=en) the outputed column whith `" ,"` to gat all occurrences of number with a length of `8`
- Note: to get the numbers with the length of N just replace 8 in the [`FILTER`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197?hl=en) function with a cell refrence.